# Get directory size with xen image

Tags: linux, command, xen, du

I want to check the size of my directory.

directory is xen domU image.

directory name is xendisk

```
du -sh ./xendisk
```

returns 5.4G.

but xen domU Image size is 10G.

[ls -alh and du -sh image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uifer.png)

what happened?

Comment: thanks,  Zumo de Vidrio. i only speak a little english. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a [sparse file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sparse_file) for your image. If you used a command like `truncate -s 10G domU.img` to create the image then this would be the result.

The wiki which I have linked has more information but basically a sparse file is one where the empty parts of the file take no space. This is useful when dealing with VMs because in most cases your VM will only take a fraction of the space available to it so using a sparse file will mean that it takes far less space on your filesystem (as you have observed). The article states that this is acheived using the following mechanism:

> When reading sparse files, the file system transparently converts
>   metadata representing empty blocks into "real" blocks filled with zero
>   bytes at runtime. The application is unaware of this conversion.

If you need to check the size with `du` you may be interested in the `--apparent-size` option, which will include all of the unallocated blocks in the calculation. Therefore you could use this command if you need the output to match what `ls` is telling you:

```
du -sh --apparent-size ./xendisk
```